# How to install MySQL in CentOS use RPM?

Tags: mysql, centos, rpm

My OS is CentOS 6.3（64bit)，I downloaded the rpm from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/, and I had checked the MD5, they are OK.
I use "rpm -ivh MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm" to install mysql, it just show many commands like "file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64", but there is no folder named mysql in /usr/share. What should I do?
Below is all of the commands show:

> [root@client setup]# rpm -ivh MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm 
>   Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64
>   file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-community-5.1.73-1.rhel5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64

Comment: I did not uninstall all of the mysql components which is contained by CentOS, so there are some conflicts. When I run rpm -e --nodeps mysql-libs, it OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall the `mysql-libs-5.1`

```
rpm -e --nodeps mysql`-libs
```